Moviepy doesn't blur video
I'm trying to create a video that keeps the proportions of the original (horizontal) video centered. Also, there should be a blurred background around the video that fills the entire screen. This should result in a vertical video with a small video superimposed on it with the proportions of the horizontal video preserved. The input video has a resolution: width 960 and 540 heght.
My current code:
from moviepy import VideoFileClip, ColorClip, CompositeVideoClip, ImageClip, concatenate_videoclips, vfx

def x1(t):
    return 960 * (t / video.duration)

def y1(t):
    return 1920 * (t / video.duration)

scaled_clip = video.resized(new_size=(960, 1920))
blurred_clip = scaled_clip.with_effects([vfx.HeadBlur(fx=x1, fy=y1, radius=20)])
blurred_clip = blurred_clip.with_position('center')

composite_clip = CompositeVideoClip([blurred_clip , scaled_clip])
composite_clip.write_videofile('output.mp4', codec='libx264', audio_codec="aac", fps=video.fps)

I recently started learning MoviePy, I found in the documentation that HeadBlur is used in a similar way, but I didn't find any examples. Generally on the internet the information is only about versions earlier than 2.0.0. The earlier versions used Blur and the current version uses HeadBlur, but it doesn't blur my video. Also I'm not sure if the x1 and y1 functions are calculating the coordinates for blur correctly
Any reply would be appreciated.
Version Python: 3.11
Version Moviepy: 2.1.1
Version Pillow: 11.0.0
Version ffmpeg-python: 0.2.0
